# Error while installing laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I got this error while installing laravel in composer. The message is AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED (PACKAGIST.ORG).

I read all the reference but still not working.. Anyone who knows how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/10-08-2014-problem-installing-laravel-authentication-required

Comment: is there another way without setting a variable in http_proxy?

Comment: As far as I know that problem occurs if certain ports are not open on your router/firewall. Also try `composer diagnose` and see if it tells you anything meaningful.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs>composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK

Comment: composer works well i don't know what to do about this one ... cause i've been transferred to new pc that's why i need to install a fresh laravel installation